# colorbox stops working after replacing div element using replacewith

Tags: jquery, colorbox, replacewith

I am having issues with colorbox after implementing replacewith code.

I have two elements that are being replaced using replacewith. Both these elements when clicked show a colorbox for the content desired. However if i use replacewith to change the content of these elements it will not allow colorbox to load the proper div content.

colorbox script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});
})
```

Jquery Replacewith script

```
$("div.en").click(function(){
$('div.lang').replaceWith('<div class="lang"><div class="DE">German</div></div>');
$('div.pagetitle').replaceWith('<h1 id="page-title" class="title">Online Store Coming Soon</h1>');
$('div.view-cat').replaceWith('<div class="view-cat"><a class="inline" href="#inline_catalog">See Our Products</a></div>');
$('div.splash-order').replaceWith('<div class="splash-order"><a class="inline" href="#inline_order">Order/Contact Us</a></div>');
});
```

I did notice that the both a.class's are inline here but once page is loaded its 'inline cboxelement' even using this it would not allow me to load the correct content

I have also tried adding the data to the change that replacewith makes but this makes the element stay the same as before

```
$('div.splash-order').replaceWith($('<div class="splash-order"><a class="inline" href="#inline_order">Order/Contact Us</a></div>', $(data)));
```

Any help is grateful. Thanks